# ASP.NET MVC3 C# - when user clicks button, change record in DB from 1 to 2 and viceversa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Basically a button functionality the changes the data in a record in a database.

Pseudo:

If record in DB = 1, on button click, change to 2
Else if record in DB = 2, on button click, change to 1

Thank in advance for any tips/help

Comment: Not much detail there .. Its very easy to do but need a little more detail. Are you using Entity framework? Do you have any current code on what your attempting to do?

Comment: Yes I am using the EF and its a database-first intranet app.

Comment: This is what I have in the view to loop through and display the 'posts'  that have the Private_ID of '1'

Comment: foreach
    (var post in Model.tb_SH_Forum_Posts.Where(w => w.Private_ID == 1).OrderBy(o=>o.Post_Date))
    {
    
        <div class ="post">
<fieldset>
            <p class="post_details">At post.Post_Date By post.Username            
            </p>
            post.Post_Desc

Comment: using (Html.BeginForm("DetailsChanged", "Thread", new { id = post.Post_ID }))
              {
            <input type="submit" name="hidePost" value="submit" />
              }

              <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Private_ID", String.Empty)
              </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
        </div>

Comment: sorry, I had to take out the @'s

Comment: So when you post back you need to accept the model your posting and do a check on it. Retrieve the record from the database, check if its 1 or 2 and make the relevant changes.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm struggling with the 'make the changes' bit

Comment: Posted an answer, its semi sudo. Makes the assumption your using a repository pattern/dependency injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudo controller action.

```
public ActionResult DetailsChanged(DetailsRepository detailsRepository, Details detailsModel)
{
  if(!ModelState.Valid)
{
   ViewData["Error"] = "Error";
   return View();
}

Details newDetails = detailsRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == detailsModel.Id);
if(newDetails != null)
{
   if(newDetails.Id == 1)
   {
      newDetails.Id = 2;
   } else {
      newDetails.Id = 2;
   }
   detailsRepository.SaveChanges();
   return View();
 }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks ever so much!  Really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Sorry for the blunt answer, busy day!

Answer (score 2):

Amy you can edit your question and post the code there and apply proper formatting.

Since it is your 1st web app and it is tips/ help you are looking for :

1. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/09/free-video-training-asp-net-mvc-3-features.aspx
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514(v=vs.98).aspx

These links will help you understand web-apps and MVC3 better - Come back here with any question you got after trying out these tutorials.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think you got your answer, then mark it as right, for the community. Look for the green tick mark on the left of this answer.